# Finder can’t find a way to work

Tags: macbook-pro, finder, safari

Finder and Safari seem to have this weird problem. A pop up will appear asking “Finder was unexpectedly quit. Do you want to reopen your windows?” This window will freeze (spinning wheel, not able to click, touch bar also doesn’t work) and reopen no matter what. This is the same for Safari, except Safari will stop when force quit. I have tried force quitting Finder, restarting, updating, killing the process in the Terminal, clearing the saved state in the Terminal, and force quitting in the Application Monitor. I am on High Sierra, and will get version number soon.

**Edit:** Recent hangs seems to be increasing by a rate of 1 a second.
**Edit:** Safari works in restore mode (cmd+r)

Comment: Which version of macOS do you have on our Mac?

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking this should happen *rarely.* That it happens with great regularity points to something wrong with the system. The easiest, first step, would be to use a utility like [Onyx](https://www.titanium-software.fr/en/onyx.html). Run the automate tab with no apps running and reboot. It will clean caches, do maintenance scripts and verify files.

If that did not fix it I would then look at the possibility that the Finder and Safari preferences files are corrupt. Look for said files in ~/Library/Preferences and /Library/Preferences. Move anything with safari and finder in the name to the desktop and reboot.

If you are **still** having problems I would find and download the latest "Combo updater" for your version of macOS. Run it, and reboot when asked. That should repair any problems with the Safari and Finder apps.

Still not working? Hmmmm.... well try those first

Comment: If you are stuck in my situation, you are going to need Homebrew to install anything, so you would need brew cask install onyx in order to install this.

Comment: Or start in Safe Mode

Comment: Ah! Any way I can give OnyX the permissions it needs to run without the finder? @steve safe mode doesn’t help :(

Comment: Start Mode clears out lots of cruft. Give that a try. Costs nothing but a few keypresses.